# How to determine if a load cell is quarter-bridge, half-bridge or full-bridge?

Tags: load-cell, wheatstone-bridge, full-bridge

Im looking to purchase 4 disk type load cells for weighing applications but it doesn't mention what configuration it is in (quarter bridge, half bridge etc.) Is it safe to assume 2 wire load cells = quarter bridge (1-resistive element), 3 wire load cells = half bridge (2 resistive elements) and 4 wire load cells = full-bridge (4 resistive elements)?

Datasheet:
[Part1](https://cf.shopee.com.my/file/fd1beba845e53916d6a7ac85364b688b)
[Part2](https://cf.shopee.com.my/file/a7dc8828c1fa3c507de9836a6e8d31dd)

Also if it is a full bridge can I just wire all 4 cell's Sig+ and Sig- in parallel into 1 HX711 module to average out the readings? Most of the discussions out there keep mentioning requiring 4 separate HX711's or a combinator board but I think thats to take individual readings of each sensor separately?

Id appreciate some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: The data sheet pictures give me no confidence that they are useful devices.

Comment: That is a full-bridge. page 2 of the datasheet gives you the 'pinout' of the wires - a cell with Exc+, Exc-, Sig+, Sig- can only be a full-bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 wires is full bridge, but it may or may not have 4 active elements.

Parallel wiring will average the readings fairly well. use the same type and length of wires on all load cells